# Bean injection in json serializer

Tags: java

I have a interface which cntaining two implementations.

```
public interface IEncryptDecryptService {

String encrypt(String text);

String decrypt(String text);
}
```

one class is

```
 @Service("SunJks")
 public class GeneralEncryptDecryptServiceImpl implements 
 IEncryptDecryptService {
  public String encrypt{
  }
  public String decrypt{
  }

 }
```

another class is

```
 @Service("SafenetHsm")
 public class SafenetHsmEncryptDecryptServiceImpl implements 
 IEncryptDecryptService {
 public String encrypt{
  }
  public String decrypt{
  }
 }
```

I want to inject one of two classes in  another class.

```
@Component
public class LogService implements ILogService {


@Resource(name = "${vault.encryptdecrypt.provider}")
private IEncryptDecryptService edservice;

public display{
edservice.encrypt("***");
}
```

This is the class where i need two inject the one of the two beans.

In application.properties i have configured that

```
#Provider Configurer
vault.encryptdecrypt.provider=SunJks
```

then "GeneralEncryptDecryptServiceImpl"is injected.

```
#Provider Configurer
vault.encryptdecrypt.provider=SafenetHsm
```

then SafenetHsmEncryptDecryptServiceImpl is  injected into the "LogService" class.

It works fine.

and if i implement same thing in Custom JsonSerializer class it is not working,bean is not injected.

```
 @Component
 public class MaskSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Xclass> {

 @Resource(name = "${vault.encryptdecrypt.provider}")
 private IEncryptDecryptService edservice;

 @Override
 public void serialize(Xclass value, JsonGenerator gen, 
 SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

    String str = value.getPersistenceValue();

    String strr = edservice.encrypt(str);

    gen.writeStartObject();

    gen.writeFieldName(strr);
    gen.writeEndObject();

}
```

i am getting nullpointer exception at edservice.encrypt(str) in above class.

Bean is not injected????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You explained a lot what you are doing with some code. Rather try to give us a minimal but complete code example.