# custom json serializer (Bean injection)

Tags: java

I have a interface which cntaining two implementations.

```
   public interface IEncryptDecryptService {

   String encrypt(String text);

   String decrypt(String text);

   }
```

one class is

```
  @Service("SunJks")
  public class GeneralEncryptDecryptServiceImpl implements 
  IEncryptDecryptService {
  public String encrypt{
  }
  public String decrypt{
  }

  }
```

another class is

```
   @Service("SafenetHsm")
   public class SafenetHsmEncryptDecryptServiceImpl implements 
   IEncryptDecryptService {
   public String encrypt{
   }
   public String decrypt{
   }
   }
```

I want to inject one of two classes in another class.

```
   @Component
  public class LogService implements ILogService {


  @Resource(name = "${vault.encryptdecrypt.provider}")
  private IEncryptDecryptService edservice;

  public display{
  edservice.encrypt("***");
  }
```

This is the class where i need two inject the one of the two beans.

In application.properties i have configured that

```
 #Provider Configurer
 vault.encryptdecrypt.provider=SunJks
```

then "GeneralEncryptDecryptServiceImpl"is injected.

```
  #Provider Configurer
  vault.encryptdecrypt.provider=SafenetHsm
```

then SafenetHsmEncryptDecryptServiceImpl is injected into the "LogService" class.

it works fine.
and if i implement same thing in Custom JsonSerializer class it is not working,bean is not injected.

```
    @Component
    public class MaskSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Xclass> {

    @Resource(name = "${vault.encryptdecrypt.provider}")
     private IEncryptDecryptService edservice;

   @Override
    public void serialize(Xclass value, JsonGenerator gen, 
   SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

    String str = value.getPersistenceValue();

    String strr = edservice.encrypt(str);

    gen.writeStartObject();

    gen.writeFieldName(strr);
    gen.writeEndObject();

    }
```

i am getting nullpointer exception at edservice.encrypt(str) in above class.

Bean is not injected????

Comment: Could you provide information on what frameworks or library for the dependency injection and how far you configure it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bean injection in json serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50981534/bean-injection-in-json-serializer)

Answer (score 0):

From your code I'm assuming you are using Spring. I can think of two reason why field edservice may be null null:

1. Property vault.encryptdecrypt.provider is not found in its application context.
2. Bean(s) with given name(s) are not found in its application context.

You can add

```
@Value("vault.encryptdecrypt.provider") private String provider;
```

to class MaskSerializer to determine if the property is found - if it is then you'll know that the bean and not the property is missing from the application context. Then you simply need to define that particular bean in that particular context. Otherwise you 'll need to define an appropriate PropertySource to read your property file.

The above is of course assuming that MaskSerializer and LogService beans are in different application contexts. Otherwise the only thing I can think of is that you're doing this:

```
MaskSerializer maskSerializer = new MaskSerializer();
```

instead of this (or equivalent with @Resource or @Inject):

```
@Autowired MaskSerializer maskSerializer;
```

somewhere in your code.